# How to have a regular object class that does its own stuff be a subclass of NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

Currently, I have two different classes, Alarm and AlarmMO, AlarmMO being the subclass of NSManagedObject. I'm trying to combine these two into one object class if possible, and I'm having some trouble. How is the best way to do this?

This is what I have currently, and I'm getting all sorts of errors:

```
class Alarm: NSManagedObject {

    //MARK: Properties
    @NSManaged var alarmTime: Double
    @NSManaged var alarmNumber: Int
    @NSManaged var startTimeInterval: Double
    @NSManaged var endTimeInterval: Double
    @NSManaged var note: String
    @NSManaged var notificationUuids: [String]
    @NSManaged var recurrenceIndex: Int
    var recurrence: RecurrenceOptions = .today
    let NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_NOTIFICATIONS_CREATED_AT_ONE_TIME = 10

}

extension Alarm {

convenience init?(alarmNumber: Int, timeIntervals: TimeIntervals, note: String, recurrence: RecurrenceOptions) {

    self.alarmNumber = alarmNumber
    self.note = note
    self.recurrence = recurrence
    self.notificationUuids = [String]()

    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .timeZone, .hour, .minute], from: date)
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = currentDateComponents.year
    dateComponents.month = currentDateComponents.month
    dateComponents.timeZone = currentDateComponents.timeZone
    dateComponents.day = currentDateComponents.day

    let startInterval = Alarm.convertToTimeDouble(hour: timeIntervals.hourStartInterval, minute: timeIntervals.minuteStartInterval)
    let endInterval = Alarm.convertToTimeDouble(hour: timeIntervals.hourEndInterval, minute: timeIntervals.minuteEndInterval)
    self.startTimeInterval = startInterval
    self.endTimeInterval = endInterval
    if endInterval < startInterval {
        os_log("Error: Alarm time endInterval is before startInterval", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
        return nil
    }
    self.alarmTime = Double.random(in: startInterval ... endInterval)

    let hour = Alarm.extractHourFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: self.alarmTime)
    let minute = Alarm.extractMinuteFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: self.alarmTime)
    os_log("Attempting to create alarm with time %d:%02d", log: OSLog.default, type: .info, hour, minute)

    createNotifications(dateComponents: dateComponents)

}

public static func convertToTimeDouble(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Double {

    return Double(hour) + (Double(minute) / 60.0)

}

public static func extractHourFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: Double) -> Int {

    return Int(floor(alarmTimeDouble))

}

public static func extractMinuteFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: Double) -> Int {

    return Int(round((alarmTimeDouble - floor(alarmTimeDouble)) * 60))

}

func createNotifications(dateComponents: DateComponents) {

    switch (self.recurrence) {
    case .today:
        self.createNotification(for: dateComponents)
    case .tomorrow:
        self.createNotification(for: self.day(after: dateComponents))
    case .daily:
        var numberOfCreatedNotifications = 0
        var currentDay: DateComponents? = dateComponents
        while numberOfCreatedNotifications < self.NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_NOTIFICATIONS_CREATED_AT_ONE_TIME {
            self.createNotification(for: currentDay)
            currentDay = self.day(after: currentDay)
            numberOfCreatedNotifications += 1
        }
    }

}

//MARK: Private functions

private func createNotification(for dateComponents: DateComponents?) {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Random Alarm"
    content.subtitle = "It's time!"
    content.body = self.note
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    guard let dateComponents = dateComponents else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap dateComponents in createNotification() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    self.notificationUuids.append(uuidString)

    guard let day = dateComponents.day else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap dateComponents.day in createNotification() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
    guard let hour = dateComponents.hour else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap dateComponents.hour in createNotification() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
    guard let minute = dateComponents.minute else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap dateComponents.minute in createNotification() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
    os_log("Creating notification for day: %d, time: %d:%02d, with uuid=%s", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, day, hour, minute, uuidString)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("error \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

private func day(after dateComponents: DateComponents?) -> DateComponents? {

    let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent

    guard let dateComponents = dateComponents,
        let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents),
        let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)
        else {
            os_log("Could not calculate tomorrow in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return nil
    }
    let newDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .timeZone, .hour, .minute], from: tomorrow)
    return newDateComponents

}

}
```

Comment: You don't want an `init` method in the extension. You can create a static function that returns a new instance of `Alarm`. You shouldn't need to create the base class; Core Data should do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AlarmMO` is your entity in Core Data, then the `AlarmMO` object should be created for you.  You can use an extension to add any other behaviour you need.

While you could create a new initialiser, I would probably take a factory approach using a static function:

```
extension AlarmMO {

    static func newAlarm(context: NSManagedObjectContext, alarmNumber: Int, timeIntervals: TimeIntervals, note: String, recurrence: RecurrenceOptions) -> AlarmMO? {

        let startInterval = Alarm.convertToTimeDouble(hour: timeIntervals.hourStartInterval, minute: timeIntervals.minuteStartInterval)
        let endInterval = Alarm.convertToTimeDouble(hour: timeIntervals.hourEndInterval, minute: timeIntervals.minuteEndInterval)

        if endInterval < startInterval {
            os_log("Error: Alarm time endInterval is before startInterval", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
            return nil
        }
        let newAlarm = AlarmMO(context: context)
        newAlarm.alarmNumber = alarmNumber
        newAlarm.note = note
        newAlarm.recurrence = recurrence
        newAlarm.notificationUuids = [String]()
        newAlarm.alarmTime = Double.random(in: startInterval ... endInterval)
        newAlarm.startTimeInterval = startInterval
        newAlarm.endTimeInterval = endInterval

        return newAlarm
    }

    var recurrence: RecurrenceOptions {
        get {
            return RecurrenceOptions(rawValue: self.recurrenceIndex)!
        }

        set {
            self.recurrenceIndex = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }

    var hour: Int {
        return Int(floor(self.alarmTime))
    }

    var minute: Int {
        return Int(round((self.alarmTime - floor(self.alarmTime)) * 60))
    }

    func scheduleNotification() {
        os_log("Attempting to create alarm with time %d:%02d", log: OSLog.default, type: .info, self.hour, self.minute)
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .timeZone, .hour, .minute], from: date)
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.year = currentDateComponents.year
        dateComponents.month = currentDateComponents.month
        dateComponents.timeZone = currentDateComponents.timeZone
        dateComponents.day = currentDateComponents.day
        createNotifications(dateComponents: dateComponents)
    }


    // Note:  This probably should be in TimeIntervals, rather than here
    public static func convertToTimeDouble(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Double {
        return Double(hour) + (Double(minute) / 60.0)
    }
```

}